# About branch points of a holomorphic map

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $F:X \to Y$ be a holomorphic map between Riemann surfaces. $q \in Y$ is a branch point if it is the image of a ramification point. How to prove that the set of branch points is a discrete subset of $Y$. This is from Rick Miranda's *Algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces*. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is a mistake. I don't believe branch points is always discrete. However, it's discrete for compact $X$ and $Y$ supposedly. I'm about to make a question about this. In the mean time, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813927/set-of-branch-points-isnt-discrete-but-branch-points-are-isolated

Comment: Thanks a lot.@JohnSmithKyon

Comment: You're welcome yuan. how about upvoting and accepting my answer then?

Comment: From Miranda page 45, after Lemma 4.4, he said that "the above lemma shows that the points of the domain where $F$ has multiplicity at least two form a discrete set". So basically it is the set of ramification point that is discrete, where did you read from Miranda that states the set of branch point is discrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to say $F$ is non-constant. Then again, I guess $Ram(F)$ is not defined for $F$ non-constant.

In general for any map $F: X \to Y$ of any topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ with $X$ compact and $Y$ Fréchet/T1 and for any closed discrete subspace $A$ of $X$, we have $F(A)$ discrete.

Proof: Closed discrete subspaces $A$ of compact is finite $\implies$ $A$ is finite $\implies$ $F(A)$ is finite $\implies$ $F(A)$ is discrete because finite subspaces of Fréchet/T1 are discrete. QED

Apply this to the case of $A=Ram(F)$ when $F$ is a non-constant holomorphic map between connected Riemann surfaces with $X$ compact (and thus $F$ is surjective, open, closed and proper and $Y$ is compact) to get $F(A)=Branch(F)$ is discrete.

In particular, this means we do not use that $F$ is proper, closed, open, surjective, non-constant or holomorphic or that $X$ is connected or that $Y$ is connected. We can relax this to $X$ compact (and not necessarily Riemann surface) and $Y$ Fréchet/T1 (and not necessarily Riemann surface, Hausdorff/T2 or compact).